# p:commandButton is not calling action method after enabling the Button

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

In the following code I'm disabling the Command-Button by default and enabling after any change in the Input.
Button is enabling fine but,
Action method [**reconfirmAction()**] of the button is not called when the button is Enabled, using Client Side API method

```
button_widget.enable()
```

Here is the code:

```
<h:form id="reConfirmForm">
    <h:outputLabel>User Name</h:outputLabel>
    <h:inputText value="#{myBean.userName}" onchange="btnWigetVar.enable()"/><br/>

    <h:outputLabel>Email</h:outputLabel>
    <h:inputText value="#{myBean.userEmail}" onchange="btnWigetVar.enable()"/><br/>

    <p:commandButton value="Re-Confirm" widgetVar="btnWigetVar" action="#{myBean.reconfirmAction}" disabled="true"/>
</h:form>
```

Im using Primeface 3.5 and Mojarra 2.1.13

Comment: It would be better disabling the `<p:commandButton>` on the window load instead of using `disabled="true"`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza : I tried that too It didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable the button using JSF not JavaScript.

```
<p:commandButton id="testbutton" value="Re-Confirm" widgetVar="btnWigetVar" action="#{myBean.reconfirmAction}" disabled="#{!bean.enabled}"/>
```

Bean:

```
private boolean enabled;

public void enableButton() {
enabled = true;
}

public boolean isEnabled() {
return enabled;
}
```

You can listen on the change in the inputfield with Ajax:

```
 <h:inputText value="#{myBean.userEmail}">
     <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{bean.enableButton}" update="testbutton"/>
 </h:inputText>
```

Also make sure that the bean is at least @ViewScoped